# Erro em criar colunas no CSS

Tags: css

Colegas.

Assumi um projeto agora com uma estrutura já pronta, porém estou levando uma surra com o css do site. Quando é incluído mais uma sala nesse projeto, as divs não ficam alinhadas em 3. Vejam:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**O código HMTL/PHP:**

```
while($jmSeg = mysqli_fetch_object($sqlSeg)){ ?>
<div class="hr-corpo">
        <div class="hr-container-campos">
                <p class="hr-container-campos-sala">SALA <?php  echo $jmSeg->sala; ?></p> <!-- SALA 01 -->
            <?php
                $sqlI = mysqli_query($conecta,"SELECT * FROM `horarios` WHERE dia = 'Segunda e Quarta' and sala = '".$jmSeg->sala."' and status = '1' ORDER BY hora");
                while ($horasI = mysqli_fetch_object($sqlI)) {
                    echo"<div class=\"hr-campos\">
                            <p><span class=\"hr\">".utf8_encode($horasI->hora)."</span><span class=\"hr-atividade\">".$horasI->atividade."</span><br/><span class=\"hr-professor\">Prof. ".$horasI->professor."</span></p>
                          </div>";
                 }
             ?>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php }  ?>
```

**CSS:**

```
.hr-corpo{
    width:30%; margin:0% 1.666666666666667% 4% 1.666666666666667%; background:rgba(0,0,0,0.0); min-height:10px; display:inline-block; padding:0%; float:left;}/*CORPO DA AGENDA*/

.hr-container-campos-sala{
    font-size:0.7em;}
```

Comment: Se bem entendi, você gostaria que as divs fiquem alinhadas em 3 colunas  e que por exemplo a div4 fique abaixo da div1 e assim por diante?

Comment: Olá Will Ramos. Exatamente. Me desculpe por não poder passar mais informações, pois como eu disse no post, esse projeto já estava pronto e quando assumi, percebi que isso ocorre quando a inclui mais salas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você procura se chama masonry, e pode ser feito utilizando a propriedades "collumn" do css, segue abaixo um exemplo da propriedade com responsibilidade para mobile.

CSS:

```
body { font: 1em/1.67 'Open Sans', Arial, Sans-serif; margin: 0; background: #e9e9e9; }
.wrapper { width: 95%; margin: 50px auto; }
.masonry { margin: 10px 0; padding: 0; column-gap: 10px; column-rule:dashed #FF0000 5px}
.item { display: inline-block; background: #fff; padding: 20px; margin: 0 0 10px 0; width: 100%;-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; }

@media only screen and (min-width: 400px) {
.masonry { -moz-column-count: 2; -webkit-column-count: 2; column-count: 2; }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
.masonry { -moz-column-count: 3; -webkit-column-count: 3; column-count: 3; }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
.masonry { -moz-column-count: 10; -webkit-column-count: 5; column-count: 5; }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
.wrapper { width: 1260px; }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="masonry">
        <div class="item" style="height:180px">1asdasdasdadasd</div>
        <div class="item" style="height:180px">2asdasdasdadasd</div>
        <div class="item" style="height:270px">3asdasdasdadasd</div>
        <div class="item" style="height:260px">4asdasdasdadasd</div>
        <div class="item" style="height:200px">5asdasdasdadasd</div>
        <div class="item" style="height:260px">6asdasdasdadasd</div>
        <div class="item" style="height:160px">7asdasdasdadasd</div>
        <div class="item" style="height:100px">8asdasdasdadasd</div>
        <div class="item" style="height:170px">9asdasdasdadasd</div>
        <div class="item" style="height:300px">10asdasdasdadasd</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Olá Will. Obrigado.